# MySQL (MariaDB) - "Data too long for column" for a very short value, not reproducible elsewhere

Tags: mysql, mariadb, datatypes

I have a table `logs` with a column `info` - the type is `text`. I get an error running the following query:

> insert into logs (date_time, info, log_code, company_id,
>   updated_at, created_at) values ('2019-04-06 22:38:58',
>   'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
>   508, 410, '2019-04-30 01:23:45', '2019-04-30 00:00:00');
>
> ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'Info' at row 1

Unfortunately the error can't be reproduced in another table. If I run:

`create table test like logs`

and then run the same query on `test` then it works.

Even with unicode this amount of data shouldn't be a problem for a data type that can hold over 65 kilobytes.

I've been looking for a solution for a couple hours and can't find anything. And it's especially odd that it can't be reproduced on another server or even on the same server in an identical table.

---

Results of `describe logs`:

```
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type                                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                    | int(10) unsigned                      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| company_id            | int(10) unsigned                      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| another_column1       | int(10) unsigned                      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date_time             | timestamp                             | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| log_code              | int(11)                               | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| info                  | text                                  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| another_column2       | varchar(255)                          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| another_column3       | tinyint(1)                            | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| type                  | enum('log','event','warning','error') | NO   |     | log     |                |
| created_at            | timestamp                             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at            | timestamp                             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at            | timestamp                             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| another_column4       | int(10) unsigned                      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Show table's DDL. Check the table storage for errors. Check if some trigger exists.

Comment: Do you get a warning when you insert to the `test` table? Are you somehow inadvertently switching between strict and non-strict `sql_mode`?

Comment: @Akina As it turns out my DB administrator added a trigger that copies the data to another table when critical error are logged. And that table has a wrong datatype. Thanks for pointing me to this. If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as the solution.